# Vector functions in pytorch to apply autograd to them

Tags: pytorch, autograd

If I have a tensor `x`.

Can I define a vector function, say `f(x) = (3x, x+2)`, and obtain its derivative `df/dx`?

In a nutshell: I want a way to define such a vector function, from which I can get its gradient.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so using [`torch.autograd.functional.jacobian`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.1/generated/torch.autograd.functional.jacobian.html#torch.autograd.functional.jacobian), providing the function and input:

```
>>> jacobian(lambda x: (3*x, x+2), inputs=torch.tensor([3.]))
```

In this case the result is `df/dx = (3, 1)` for all `x`.